# Count rows in mysql with php when have specific string

Tags: php, mysql, count

I have a table in my database named `visitor_table` . Within table i have a column named `visitor_affiliate`. I want to get the count of the rows when `visitor_affiliate = "someurer"` .

I want to get the count as number. I already have this code but i don't know how to get the count only for the rows containing the string. I currently get the number of all rows,

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visitor_table");   
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);    
echo "$num_rows Rows\n";
```

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code! They are [in the process of being deprecated.](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated)

Comment: mysql functions are going to be obsolete soon! use `PDO`..see this... http://php.net/pdo . they are safer and more semantic. but this post does not show any kind of research work..

Comment: i tried all answers and i get Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visitor_table WHERE `visitor_affiliate` = 'someurer'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo $num_rows . " Rows\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You can ask MySQL to return the count:

   ```sql
   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visitor_table WHERE visitor_affiliate = 'someurer'
   ```
2. You shouldn't be using the ancient (deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0, soon to be removed entirely) MySQL extension for writing new code—use instead [the improved MySQLi extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [the PDO abstraction layer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), both of which enable you to pass variables to the database in [a safe, parameterised, fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496) that ensures they are not evaluated for SQL (and therefore prevents SQL injection attacks):

   ```
   $dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
   $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
   $qry = $dbh->prepare('
     SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visitor_table WHERE visitor_affiliate = ?
   ');
   $qry->execute(['someurer']);
   echo $qry->fetchColumn(), ' rows';
   ```

Answer (score 0):

With what little information you have given just try this-

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visitor_table Where visitor_affiliate like '%someurer%'");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
echo "$num_rows Rows\n";
```

Comment: @Stauroula: you should avoid using mysql_* function as they are deprecated.

Comment: i tried that and i get this Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: It means your query is failing. Just try to run query in query browser.

Comment: i tried it without Where visitor_affiliate like '%someurer%' but i still not get the count of rows.....

Answer (score 0):

The deprecated MySQL:

```
$res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM visitor_table');
echo 'Number of rows:'.mysql_num_rows($res);
```

Procedural MySQLi:

```
$tu = mysqli_prepare($DBH,'SELECT * FROM visitor_table');
mysqli_execute($tu);
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($tu);
echo $num_rows.' rows\n';
```

mysql has been deprecated. Please use mysqli.
Using MySQLi bind_param to get your result:

```
$someuser = 'Dave';
$DBH = mysqli_connect('localhost','user','pass','database');
$query = mysqli_prepare($DBH,'SELECT * FROM visitor_table WHERE user = ?');
mysqli_bind_param($query,'s',$someuser);
mysqli_execute($query);
mysqli_bind_result($id,$user,$tabCol1,$tabCol2);
while(mysqli_fetch_result){
    $row = $row +1;
    echo $user.': was found in the record with ID of: '.$id;
}
echo 'total records found:'.$row;
```

That's one way of doing it as I'm not completely 100% sure about using a `mysqli_num_row()` with the query above.

Comment: i get this Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: @StauroulaXalkia which example did you use? `mysql_num_rows();` and `mysqli_num_rows();` need a resource parameter. If you look at the top example I've used `mysql_num_rows($res);` $res is my query variable. Which is the equivalent to writing `mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('SELECT * FROM visitor_table'));`. `mysql_num_rows();` will always need a parameter :)

Comment: Actually i used mysql_num_rows and got the warning i wrote....when i am using Mysqli example the page cannot be found.... i get 404 error

Comment: @StauroulaXalkia 404 error :S that's a strange one. Can't be related to using mysqli unless you haven't put in your localhost and other parameters for the mysqli_connection correctly? But they wouldn't return as a 404. come to think of it I think I've used the wrong connection method for mysqli procedural :p lol I'll update :)